# PHP return array of matching KEY NAMES and there values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a terrible time trying to pull out some values out of an array.  Here is a slimmed down version of the array.

```
$properties = array( array( PropertyID => 2845, 
                  Address_1 => "1234 Any street",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_00 => "23428.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00 => "Front of House",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_01 => "29872.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01 => "Master Bedroom",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_02 => "29834.jpg"
                ),
              array( PropertyID => 2845, 
                  Address_1 => "555 This street",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_00 => "234234.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00 => "Front of House",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_01 => "298724.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01 => "Second Bedroom",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_02 => "298346.jpg"
                ),
              array( PropertyID => 2845, 
                  Address_1 => "333 Main street",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_00 => "2342845.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00 => "Lounge",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_01 => "2987246.jpg",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01 => "Front of House",
                  MEDIA_IMAGE_02 => "2983434.jpg"
                ),
         );
```

There is a **massive** amount of data in each sub array I've trimmed it down for length...

I'm inserting this data into a MySQL database, however, I'm inserting the images into a separate table [PropertyID, Image, ImageText] because some properties may have more images than others.

So now that the background is out of the way.

How do I pull **just the keys of the array that match** and there info into another array?  So that I would end up with an array from the above that would end up with something similar to:

```
$property_images = array( array( PropertyID => 2845, 
                         IMAGE => "23428.jpg",
                         IMAGE_TEXT => "Front of House"),
                  array( PropertyID => 2845,
                         IMAGE => "29872.jpg",
                         IMAGE_TEXT => "Master Bedroom",
                  array( PropertyID => 2845,
                         MEDIA_IMAGE_02 => "29834.jpg"
                         IMAGE_TEXT => "Living Room"
```

I've tried sscanf to no avail and fiddle around with array_keys but haven't managed to figure out how to target the **key names** rather than the key values...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
foreach( $properties as $v ) {
 foreach( $v as $k => $m ) {     

  if( strpos($k, 'MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_') !== FALSE  ) {        
    $new_array[] = array('PropertyID' => $v['PropertyID'], 'IMAGE'=>$prev, 'IMAGE_TEXT'=>$m );
  } 

  if( strpos($k, 'MEDIA_IMAGE_') !== FALSE ) {
    $prev = $m;  //var_dump($prev);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: That's a great start!  But I need to iterate over each MEDIA_IMAGE_XX and MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_XX.

Comment: I need something like for each array_key name that matches "MEDIA_IMAGE_" + (twodigits) grab that array key's value and put it in the new array.

Comment: the 1st `foreach` will iterate over each MEDIA_IMAGE_00 and MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00. Note: MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_XX not equal to MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00.

Comment: oh ok, as you mentioned `_00` in your question, I mentioned that. I will edit my answer, give me a minute.

Comment: Right...  But I need it to grab out MEDIA_IMAGE_00, MEDIA_IMAGE_01, MEDIA_IMAGE_02, etc...  As well as, MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_00, MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_01, MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_02...  Then move onto the next sub-array and do it all over again for as many MEDIA_IMAGE_** and MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_** that are in each the sub-array

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but it's throwing out NULL for the values.  I went in and made sure that the data was there by putting `echo $k . " => " . $m . "<br />";` after the last `foreach` and it is putting out the data.  I noticed that it put out 97 PropertyID, MEDIA_IMAGE, and MEDIA_TEXT.  So it's not delineating the image keys at all...

Comment: Right!!!  I've got it! If you can update your answer to replace the `> 0` with `!== false` and the `$new_array[]` with a  `if ($value1 != NULL) {` statement.  It will update the answer for anyone else that happens along the same problem and I'll accept your answer.  Thanks again so much for the help @coder1984!!!

Comment: Here is the final code I've got working http://codepad.org/rosbSkD9  Thank you again so much for your help!